# Generically subtype a type parameter of a generic method when used by a subtype

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to achieve the following code architecture in a clean way.

There is a trait (could also be an abstract class, but I don't think it would solve this problem) which I call `Shape`, that is subtyped by two classes, `Circle` and `Rectangle`. Each of them provide custom members: a Shape has a (abstract) method `size` that allows to change the size (and is implemented by the subclasses); a Circle has a `radius` field; and a Rectangle has a `width` and a `height` fields.

Then, there is a generic trait, `Changer`, which allows doing modifications to the shapes. It is generic, `Changer[-S <: Shape]`, and is subtyped by three different classes, `SizeChanger` that changes the size of a `Shape`, `WidthChanger` that changes the width of a `Rectangle`, and `RadiusChanger` that changes the radius of a `Circle`.

Each `Changer` has a method `change(shape)` that actually executes the change specified by the `Changer`.

Finally, there is a method `change(shapeChanger)` in the `Shape` class that essentially consists in calling the `change` method of the shape `Changer` with this object.

All in all, the code looks like this:

```
trait Shape {
  def change(changer: /* This is the question */): Unit = {
    changer.change(this)
  }
  def size(s: Int): Unit
}
class Circle(var r: Int) extends Shape {
  override def size(s: Int): Unit = r = s/2
}
class Rectangle(var w: Int, var h: Int) extends Shape {
  override def size(s: Int): Unit = {
    w = s
    h = s
  }
}

trait Changer[-S <: Shape] {
  def change(shape: S): Unit
}
class Size(s: Int) extends Changer[Shape] {
  override def change(shape: Shape): Unit = shape.size(s)
}
class Radius(r: Int) extends Changer[Circle] {
  override def change(shape: Circle): Unit = shape.r = r
}
class Width(w: Int) extends Changer[Rectangle] {
  override def change(shape: Rectangle): Unit = shape.w = w
}
```

Example use of these classes:

```
val circle = new Circle(42)
val rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20)
val rectAsShape: Shape = rectangle
val widthChanger = new Width(30)
val radiusChanger = new Radius(17)
val sizeChanger = new Size(40)
val radAsChanger: Changer[Circle] = radiusChanger
val sizeAsChanger: Changer[Shape] = sizeChanger
val sizeAsCircleChanger: Changer[Circle] = sizeChanger
circle.change(radiusChanger)
circle.change(sizeChanger)
circle.change(sizeAsCircleChanger)
rectangle.change(widthChanger)
rectangle.change(sizeChanger)
rectangle.change(sizeAsChanger)
rectAsShape.change(sizeChanger)
// rectAsShape.change(widthChanger) // Shouldn't work
```

The `Changer` trait `S` parameter is specified as contravariant as technically a `SizeChanger` (and all `Changer[Shape]`) are also valid `Changer[Circle]`, as they know how to handle a `Shape`, and for example a `Circle`.

The real problem is the `change` method in the `Shape` trait. In practice, it will always look the same for each subclass of `Shape` and will just call the changer. So it should be generic and not expect a `Changer[Shape]`, but rather a `Changer[S]`, where `S` is the type of the concrete object. That way, a `Circle` can accept the more specific `Changer[Circle]` and we can still cast it to a `Shape` and call the method with a `Changer[Shape]`.

I've tried many different combinations of type parameters, using various variances and type bounds, and I didn't get the correct one.

By luck, I found that the following definition worked:

```
def change(changer: Changer[this.type]): Unit = ???
```

But I'm looking for a more generic way of doing this.

I'm pretty sure that this question is a duplicate of some other question on SO, as this pattern looks to me like it is frequent, but as I can't put a name on this pattern, I didn't find anything valid nor useful (for now).

So any name on this pattern of code (or any opinion on the bad aspects of this code) would already be helpful.

EDIT 1:

Maybe I could have added that the end goal is to use all of this in a DSL (for the Canvas API through Scala.js) that will ultimately look like

```
circle1 and circle2 change Radius(10)
circle1 and circle2 and rectangle1 change StrokeColor(Color.red) and StrokeWidth(4)
// This changes the 3 shapes' stroke color and stroke width.
```

Requiring the user to "create" a new variable each time it wants to change properties of a shape is therefore cumbersome, so the shapes have to be internally changed.

Also, there will hence be some return type instead of `Unit` for the `Shape::change` method, although I (well, we) still have to figure it out.

Comment: You probably can solve the problem using **F-Bounded Polymorphism**, something like `trait Shape[S <: Shape[S]] { this: S =>  def change(changer: Changer[S]): Unit = ...`. But, maybe a **typeclass** approach would be better, but that would play better if instead of modified the current shape, you returned a new one. See [this](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) for reference.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez these are indeed the concepts I was looking for, thanks! :)
I edited the question to explain why the `Shape`s have to be mutable in my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suppose my answer will be rather lengthy, but since you've asked for opinion on all the aspects of the code, I hope this explanation will help you to understand the general philosophy of Scala's approach.

First of all, in Scala one generally tries to avoid any mutable data structure. Why is that? Let's inspect the signature of your `change` method in the `Changer` class. It takes something (`Shape`) and returns `Unit`. One can fairly assume that `Changer` does nothing with the `Shape` itself because `Unit` doesn't signal anything except "code block finished". So the first move is to change the signature to `change(shape: S): S` to show our intent.

Okay, now we clearly have some modification going on, but we can improve the code even more by removing all the `var`s from `Circle` and `Rectangle` and making them [case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html). Case classes are a neat concept in Scala for defining immutable data structures. We can't change their state, but we can create new ones with a new state. The definition is quite simple:

```
case class Circle(r: Int) extends Shape { ... }
case class Rectangle(w: Int, h: Int) extends Shape { ... }
```

Case classes allow us to use handy `copy` method which you can read about from the link I provided above. So, now, when we don't need to mutate any `Shape` whatsoever, we can remove the `change` method from the base trait. But, of course, that means that we lose the handy `obj.change(...)` syntax. How can one deal with this?

The answer is type-class pattern. There is a [neat post](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) by Rob Norris explaining the pattern in detail. And we already have everything to implement it. We just need to write a short [implicit class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) which is basically a syntax extension.

I'll provide the most basic one you can come up with:

```
implicit class ChangerOps[S <: Shape](s: S) {
    def change(implicit c: Changer[S]): S = c.change(s)
}
```

And then you just declare your `Size`, `Radius`, `Width` as `implicit val`s (you can read about implicits [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html)) and use the syntax you've just written. Because it may be a little difficult to acknowledge all that information at once I've prepared a [code example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vpfm0JNATPGNPJwN9VsFpA) that you can fiddle with online. Note that this approach omits contravariance because you can just widen the type to get the implicit you need.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the time taken to answer, I learned a lot through your example and Rob Norris' blog post!

I very well understand that in Scala we emphasise an immutable approach.
In "my" use case, the `Shape`s have to be mutable, as they are used in a DSL written in a non-declarative way, sadly; we could redesign it so that all was declarative, but this would probably add little benefit to the end user.
I have edited the post to add an example usage of the DSL in mind. And that `change` will actually return something (still to be decided).

Comment: @Jimvy, the fact is that you're writing a DSL for Scala.js is an important addition because in many cases we can't extrapolate Scala's approaches when writing Scala.js code. In this case, however, I encourage you to decide whether the programs the DSL is intended for perform many mutations (and I mean, **a lot**) using the DSL. If they are, then, perhaps, you should digress to something more performance-oriented. In opposite case, I believe it is fine to generate new objects each time.

Comment: Also note that while you achieve readability and make your code more descriptive by using your DSL, you increase cognitive load required to process it by making objects mutable. That is because each time you mutate the object you need to think about all the places where it is used and deduce whether your mutation "here" will break the program "there".  


The DSL you presented is pretty neat and I believe it will only benefit from using immutable data.